# getformat for showing week

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

How can I set DateTimeFormat to show something like this:
"wed.-sun." "mon.-sun." "mon.-sun." "mon.-sun." "mon.-tue"

```
DateTimeFormat dtfDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd.MM");

if (rt.detalization.equals("date")) {
    dtfDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd.MM");
}
if (rt.detalization.equals("week")) {                
    dtfDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE.dd-EEE.dd");
    //how can show week from choisen day to sunday like I wrote before
}
if (rt.detalization.equals("month")) {
    dtfDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MMM");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code prints

```
     DateTimeFormat format2 = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("E");
     String format = format2.format(new Date());
     System.out.println(format); //prints "Mon"
```

So

```
if (rt.detalization.equals("week")) {  
       DateTimeFormat format2 = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("E");
    String day= format2.format(dtfDate);              
         System.out.println(day+"-Sun");

}
```